# Cannot place KActorSpawnable - UnrealScript

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I hope someone here can help me, i been trying to create an placeable actor that will be player controller, but when I try to add it via the "Actor Classes" windows, there is nothing there.

```
class BallBall extends KActorSpawnable
    placeable;

defaultproperties
{
    Begin Object Name=StaticMeshComponent0
        StaticMesh=StaticMesh'EngineMeshes.Sphere'
        bNotifyRigidBodyCollision=true
        HiddenGame=TRUE
        ScriptRigidBodyCollisionThreshold=0.001
        LightingChannels=(Dynamic=TRUE)
        DepthPriorityGroup=SDPG_Foreground
    End Object
}
```

I'm really deseperate with this, any help ***really*** apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own question, looks like my class was correct, i was just searching int the wrong place, i though i would be located directly down Actor, but it was located under Actor, -> DynamicSMActor -> KActor -> KActorSpawnable -> BallBall